# Post dialog on Facebook wall and Facebook page

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using facebook sharing API that post dialog on user wall after user login..
For example user come my site and like some thing and it share on his facebook wall..
But now I need when user share this on his wall then at a time same description will be share on facebook page that I made for my website ..
so it is possible at a time same share post on user wall and a facebook page?

I am using facebook SDK sharing API...

```
FB.init({appId: "my app id" status: true, cookie: true});
var obj = { method: 'feed', 
            link: 'http://example.php',
            picture: 'http://example.php/images/logo.png',
            name: 'Rate the best Brewery in town',
            message:'helloo how are you ??',
            caption: 'drinkbeer.in',
            description: 'I just gave a thumbs up to ('+shop_name+') on DrinkBeer.In/Asheville What is your favorite place? Vote NOW!!'
          };

function callback(response) 
{  
   if (response && response.post_id) 
   {
       alert(response.post_id);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

After your above post is completed, you can simply make another call to publish on the fan page . Just like:

```
FB.api("/pageid/feed", params);
```

---

Just like this:

```
function callback(response) 
{  
   var obj = <YOUR_PARAMETERS>;

   if (response && response.post_id) 
   {
       alert(response.post_id);
       FB.api("/<YOU_PAGE_ID>/feed", 'post', obj, function(response) {
         if (!response || response.error) {
             alert('Error occured');
         } else {
             alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
         }
       });
   } 
}
```

---

Permissions required: `manage_pages`, `publish_stream`

Comment: hi ..thankyou for your help but i am trying to post on facebook page that i make but i don't know which api work for facebook page ..
is page api is different than the above api that i show above ?

Comment: You can try your own code with "to" parameter, where youll give ur page id. Let me know wether it works or not, and dont forget to accpt the answer if worked. Good luck

Comment: can you please send me the simple code for facebook page posting api ?

Comment: i am using this code for posting facebook pagebut not working
FB.init({appId: "app_id", status: true, cookie: true});

function postToPage() {
 //alert("here")
    var page_id = 'page_id';
    FB.api('/' + page_id, {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp) {
        alert(resp.access_token)
  if(resp.access_token) {
            FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed',
                'post',
                { message: "I'm a Page!", access_token: resp.access_token }
                ,function(response) {
     alert(response)
                   //console.log(response);
            });
        }
    });
}

Comment: What do you mean by NOT WORKING? Pls tell me some details, errors, result you are getting! And are you getting `resp.access_token`? And what is `response`. Pls be clear

Comment: actually i just found this script for Posting to Fan Page as an Admin .. but its not working . if you have then you can help me ..

Comment: The script is right. Ok, last time- what's the response? error?

Comment: i call this function on click but it didnot show any thing no error nothing else ..
i did not see any response on click ..

Comment: Do you really think this is possible? Take a breath and see what is happening, I simply cant help you coz I dont know what's all happening at your end!

Comment: ahh i solve it .. 
there is a problem in a permission access by the app that i am using .. 
Permissions:

publish_stream
manage_pages

these permission are necessary for this app..
thank you for helping ..
one thing ..
can we post image with our message ?

Comment: helping link :
[http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/]

Comment: hi i need little help more ..
this api only run when admin is login ..
but i need it run for every user not only for admin ..
did you know about that ?

Comment: `but i need it run for every user not only for admin` - didnt got you. pls post another question :)

Comment: hi ..
my other question is on this page please review that . (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788036/facebook-fan-page-post-api-for-all-users)